# Open custom Wordpress admin menu item in external URL

Tags: wordpress

I have this code snippet which creates custom Wprdpress admin menu items and they show up nicely. Since these are links to the external URL I would like to open them in the external tab. Can’t figure out how to to that though. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu');

function admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu() {
    global $submenu;

    $menu_slug = "externallink"; // used as "key" in menus
    $menu_pos = 1; // whatever position you want your menu to appear

    // create the top level menu
    add_menu_page( 'external_link', 'Tutorials', 'read', $menu_slug, '', '', $menu_pos);

    // add the external links to the slug you used when adding the top level menu
    $submenu[$menu_slug][] = array('Yahoo', 'manage_options', 'https://www.yahoo.com/');
    $submenu[$menu_slug][] = array('Google', 'manage_options', 'https://www.google.com/'); 
}
```

Comment: Did my code helped to solve your problem? If yes could you please mark my answer as the right one? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work as you expect you have to create the extra jQuery function `admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu_jquery` which will open your submenu items in a new tab. This function is checking for the div's ID which is now set for each of your submenu items `newtab` and `newtab2` and the final result is `target: _blank` (new window) output. Code goes into your active theme or child theme functions.php file. Tested and works.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu');
add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu_jquery' );

function admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu() {
    global $submenu;

    $menu_slug = "externallink"; // used as "key" in menus
    $menu_pos = 1; // whatever position you want your menu to appear

    // create the top level menu
    add_menu_page( 'external_link', 'Tutorials', 'read', $menu_slug, '', '', $menu_pos);

    // add the external links to the slug you used when adding the top level menu
    $submenu[$menu_slug][] = array('<div id="newtab">Yahoo</div>', 'manage_options', 'https://www.yahoo.com/');
    $submenu[$menu_slug][] = array('<div id="newtab2">Google</div>', 'manage_options', 'https://www.google.com/'); 
}

function admin_menu_add_external_links_as_submenu_jquery() 
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {   
            $('#newtab').parent().attr('target','_blank');
            $('#newtab2').parent().attr('target','_blank');   
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```